# How to test for a time span parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, operator-overloading, case

I'm struggling with the following issue:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> 2.class
=> Fixnum
irb(main):002:0> Fixnum === 2
=> true
irb(main):003:0> 2.hours.class
=> Fixnum
irb(main):004:0> Fixnum === 2.hours
=> false
irb(main):005:0>
```

I'd like to test whether some specified parameter is a symbol or a time span. The way I thought would be the natural way in Ruby/Rails is:

```
case param
when :today then
  # do this...
when Fixnum then
  # do that...
else
  raise ArgumentError ...
end
```

As far as I can tell from ActiveSupport's source code `===` is not overridden for Fixnum. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Switching behavior based on the actual class of a variable is generally frowned upon as it breaks [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) which is such a wonderful way to program that you shouldn't throw it away by overly eager type checking. Remember: the type is irrelevant most of the time. What counts is the offered interface and behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the console, that `2.hours` can't be `Fixnum`, because it's `#inspect` method is overridden. It just pretends to be Fixnum, but it is `ActiveSupport::Duration` (see [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3018f4727621b6f2b117a2b5d75561127f2a8592/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb))

```
> 2.hours
=> 7200 seconds 
> 2.hours.to_i
=> 7200
```

Better check if it responds to some methods. If it responds to `to_i`, it is not a symbol.

```
> :today.respond_to?(:to_i)
=> false 
> 2.hours.respond_to?(:to_i)
=> true
```